Flattening groups of indices in a numpy array
Suppose I have a four-dimensional array and I would like to flatten the first two indices and the last two indices. For example, with a 2x2x2x2 array, this would yield a (2x2)x(2x2)=4x4 array. How can I do this?
In other words, I want to reindex an array in the fashion of
A_new[2*n+m,2*q+p] = A_old[m,n,p,q]
where the first two indices have been consolidated into one large index and so have the last two indices. To my knowledge, reshape doesn't allow this level of control into the reindexing. How can I achieve it?

Since this array is so small, could you provide an example input array (e.g., numpy.arange(16).reshape((2,2,2,2)) and the desired output from that

It looks like what you have in mind is a column-major reshape. NumPy defaults to a row-major reshape. You can achieve this by setting the order argument of np.reshape:
A_new = A_old.reshape(4, 4, order='F')

For example:
>>> A_old = np.arange(16).reshape(2, 2, 2 ,2)
>>> A_new = A_old.reshape(4, 4, order='F')
>>> A_new
array([[ 0,  2,  1,  3],
       [ 8, 10,  9, 11],
       [ 4,  6,  5,  7],
       [12, 14, 13, 15]])

Confirming it matches the indexing in the question:
>>> assert all(A_new[2*n+m,2*q+p] == A_old[m,n,p,q]
...            for m in range(2) for n in range(2)
...            for q in range(2) for np in range(2))


Making a sample 4d array:
In [390]: a_old = np.arange(2*2*2*2).reshape(2,2,2,2); a_old
Out[390]: 
array([[[[ 0,  1],
         [ 2,  3]],

        [[ 4,  5],
         [ 6,  7]]],


       [[[ 8,  9],
         [10, 11]],

        [[12, 13],
         [14, 15]]]])

Look at the simplest reshape:
In [391]: a_new = a_old.reshape(4,4); a_new
Out[391]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])

Trying a sample point:
In [392]: m,n,p,q = 0,1,1,0

In [393]: a_old[m,n,p,q]
Out[393]: 6

Your reindesing doesn't work:
In [394]: a_new[m+2*n, p+2*q]
Out[394]: 9

But changing the expressions a bit:
In [395]: a_new[2*m+n, 2*p+q]
Out[395]: 6

And testing that for all possible values:
In [396]: idx = np.indices((2,2,2,2),sparse=True)

In [397]: a_old[idx[0],idx[1],idx[2],idx[3]]
Out[397]: 
array([[[[ 0,  1],
         [ 2,  3]],

        [[ 4,  5],
         [ 6,  7]]],


       [[[ 8,  9],
         [10, 11]],

        [[12, 13],
         [14, 15]]]])

In [398]: a_new[2*idx[0]+idx[1],2*idx[2]+idx[3]]
Out[398]: 
array([[[[ 0,  1],
         [ 2,  3]],

        [[ 4,  5],
         [ 6,  7]]],


       [[[ 8,  9],
         [10, 11]],

        [[12, 13],
         [14, 15]]]])

@jakevdp suggests a transpose .transpose(1, 0, 3, 2)
In [399]: a_vdp = a_old.transpose(1,0,3,2).reshape(4,4); a_vdp
Out[399]: 
array([[ 0,  2,  1,  3],
       [ 8, 10,  9, 11],
       [ 4,  6,  5,  7],
       [12, 14, 13, 15]])

In [400]: a_vdp[m+2*n, p+2*q]
Out[400]: 6

In [401]: a_vdp[idx[0]+2*idx[1],idx[2]+2*idx[3]]
Out[401]: 
array([[[[ 0,  1],
         [ 2,  3]],

        [[ 4,  5],
         [ 6,  7]]],


       [[[ 8,  9],
         [10, 11]],

        [[12, 13],
         [14, 15]]]])

So if particular 'flattening' is important, transpose before reshaping.  But if you want the 2d to still 'look' like the original, change your flattening math.
